# Cesium - ImportError: Cannot import name reraise

Tags: python, importerror

I've been trying to use cesium for a project. Specifically I'm trying to import the cesium.featurize library. However when I do so I get the following error:

```
    from dask.compatibility import reraise
    ImportError: cannot import name reraise
```

I looked into the code on github [found here](https://github.com/cesium-ml/cesium/blob/master/cesium/featurize.py), and I see the cesium.featurize imports dask and dask.compatibility, which is causing the error. But I have no idea how to fix this, if it's even anything to do with my end at all? Importing cesium on its own is fine, but when i specify this library it errors. I'm really lost, as I need this library for feature extraction on a time series, and cant find any alternatives.

Comment: You're running it on Python2, right? In the featurize.py file in the cesium library, it's importing reraise from from dask.compatibility. And if you look at the code for dask.compatibility (here: https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/master/dask/compatibility.py) in line 63 it says if its python3 then it defines reraise. So you have to run it on Python3 im assuming

Comment: Ah, that sucks. My uni's system is back on python 2 so looks like i'm going to have to try a different way of doing my coursework! Regardless, appreciate the answer, if you want to add it as one I can choose as a solution if you'd like.